# Vue.js how to add index to modal window

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a problem with adding an id to a modal window.
I have several user cards that are loaded into template from json placeholder.
There has to be an optin to delete user. When click delete button modal window has to be shown to confirm the action.
I created a function in vuex store to delete the user, but i can't invoke a modal window specifically for that user.
Whenever deleted button is clicked, modal windows appear on every user card.
How do I open a modal only for the card that is being deleted?
Here is my template:

```html
<div class="staff-cards-container">
  <div class="staff-card" v-for="(staff) in allStaff" :key="staff.id">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="employee">
        <h5>{{staff.name}}</h5>
        <p>{{staff.company.name}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="options-container">
        <button class="options-btn">
          <img src="@/assets/dots.svg">
        </button>
        <div id="options-content">
          <router-link to="/staffedit">
            <button @click="goToEdit()">
              <img src="@/assets/edit.svg" class="options-icon"> Редактировать
            </button>
          </router-link>
          <button class="delete-btn" @click="showModal(staff.id)">
            <img src="@/assets/del.svg" class="options-icon">Уволить
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-wrapper">
          <div class="modal" v-show="isModalVisible" @close="closeModal">
            <p>Вы уверены что хотите уволить сторудника " {{staff.name}} " ?</p>
            <div class="confirm-btns">
              <button
                @click="(deleteStaff(staff.id)), (activateConfirm = true), (showModal)"
                class="delete-btn-modal"
              >Да</button>
              <button @click="closeModal" class="cancel-btn">Нет</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal" v-if="activateConfirm" @close="activateConfirm=false">
            <p>Сотрудник " {{staff.name}} " успешно удален</p>
            <button class="confirm-btns cancel-btn" @click="activateConfirm=false">ОК</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And script:

```js
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "stafflist",
  data() {
    return {
      search: "",
      activateConfirm: false,
      isModalVisible: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["fetchStaff", "deleteStaff"]),
    showModal() {
      this.isModalVisible = true;
    },
    closeModal() {
      this.isModalVisible = false;
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["allStaff"])
  }
};
```

Any advice will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix for the above would be:

1. Change is `isModalVisible:false` to something like `selectedId:''`
2. Pass the `staff.id` to `showModal(id)` method - this is missing from your code.
3. Set `selectedId = id`

```
    showModal() {
        this.selectedId = id;
    }
```

4. Change `v-show="isModalVisible"` to `v-show="selectedId == staff.id"`

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using boostrap-vue.

boostrap-vue already has a solution for using modals [see here](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/modal/#using-thisbvmodalshow-and-thisbvmodalhide-instance-methods).

This way you can open specific modal by their id's.

```js
let app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    staffs: [
      { id: 1, name : "Bob" },
      { id: 2, name : "Ron" },
      { id: 3, name : "John" },
      { id: 4, name : "Greg" }
      ]
  }
});
```

```html
<!-- Load Vue followed by BootstrapVue -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="staff in staffs" :key="staff.id">
    {{staff.name}}
    <b-btn @click="$bvModal.show(staff.id)" variant="danger">Delete</b-btn>
    <b-modal :id="staff.id" :title="`Delete ${staff.name} ?`">
      Are you sure you want to delete {{staff.name}} ?
    </b-modal>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you do not want to use this solution @Spiderman has a good answer.

Comment: Thank you  for your answer! I went with @Spiderman advice though.